# Docker not getting start on slave node in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, etcd, flanneld

execute below command on slave node in kubernetes cluster.

```
for SERVICES in docker; do systemctl restart $SERVICES; systemctl enable $SERVICES; systemctl status $SERVICES; done
```

got below error

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─flannel.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-04-11 11:20:10 GMT; 67ms ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 2315 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: time="2018-04-11T11:20:10Z" level=error msg="WARNING: No --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev specified, using loopback; thi...ction use"
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: time="2018-04-11T11:20:10Z" level=warning msg="Docker could not enable SELinux on the host system"
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: time="2018-04-11T11:20:10Z" level=info msg="+job init_networkdriver()"
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: Bridge ip (172.17.42.1) does not match existing bridge configuration 172.30.81.1
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: time="2018-04-11T11:20:10Z" level=info msg="-job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)"
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L docker[2315]: time="2018-04-11T11:20:10Z" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: Bridge ip (172.17.42.1) does not ma...2.30.81.1"
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 11 11:20:10 LX01511L systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: Bridge ip (172.17.42.1) does not ma...2.30.81.1"

Comment: Hi, >Docker could not enable SELinux on the host system , can you try to enable it with  `setenforce 1`

Comment: Can you provide output of [sestatus](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sestatus) command?

Comment: selinux is disabled

Comment: It should be helpful for you - https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/195